# Math system with external parameter

Tags: math-mode, equations, parameters, variable, build-system

I'm writing a document where I need to define a system with an external parameter. Here an image to make it clearer:

[image]

I'm using this current code to generate a common system, here is an example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{1.5ex}
      \begin{equation}
        \begin{dcases}
        \mathbf{\dot r} \,= \frac{dr}{dt} \;= \mathbf{v} \\
        \mathbf{\dot v} \,= \frac{dv}{dt} \;= g + \frac{\mathbf{T}}{m} \;= g + \mathbf{a_T}\\
        \dot m = \frac{dm}{dt} = -\frac{T}{g_o I_\mathrm{sp}} = -\frac{T}{c}
        \end{dcases}
       \end{equation}
\end{spreadlines}

\end{document}
```

How could I rework the code to make an external parameter appear (likewise the psi greek letter along with the equality sign)?

Thank you!

Comment: Is what you want achieved by adding `\psi =` immediately before `\begin{dcases}`?

Comment: Thank you very much @WillieWong, It's exactly what I was looking for. It was much simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say that a `dcases` environment is particularly well suited for the job at hand. I think you're better off with an `alignedat` environment, especially as it allows direct alignment of the `=` symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{spreadlines}{1.5ex}
\begin{equation}
\psi=
\left\{
    \begin{alignedat}{3}
      \dot{\mathbf{r}} &= \frac{dr}{dt} &&= \mathbf{v} \\
      \dot{\mathbf{v}} &= \frac{dv}{dt} &&= g + \frac{\mathbf{T}}{m}     &&= g + \mathbf{a_T}\\
      \dot{m}          &= \frac{dm}{dt} &&= -\frac{T}{g_o I_\mathrm{sp}} &&= -\frac{T}{c}
    \end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{spreadlines}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Definetely more elegant and typographically better @Mico. Thumbs up!